# VisualForce page embedded on custom object's page layout

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, page-layout, custom-controller

I am working on a visualforce page which is embedded on (its) custom object's page layout. The problem I am running into is as follows:

The visualforce page contains custom input fields with text describing each input box, which means we are unable to use the drag and drop functionality on the page layout. I added a save button to the visualforce page, which worked fine, but the producers are not satisfied with having to save one individual section, as well as saving the entire page at the end. Simply clicking the standard save button on the page layout will not save the fields in the visualforce page. Hence, I need a way to override the save button, to save the visualforce page's fields and then proceed as usual, by calling the save method on the object. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, don't think you're going to be able to do this without converting the whole page to a VF page.  It might make it more 'drag-and-drop' if you use fieldsets to populate the VF page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a possible way to achieve this. You have to either create the whole VF page with all the required fields and of course you will loose the drag and drop functionality or move those fields to the standard layout.

Another possible option is to automatically save in your embedded VF page when you loose the focus of a field but this depend on the logic of your page and how many fields you need to show on that VF page, I don't like this option, but again is possible with this approach.